# What is the query using the $wpdb notation that would allow to search and potentially echo posts from certain categories?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, calendar

Unfortunately my MySQL skills became quite rusty for complex queries and combined with my lack of experience in WordPress I have to succumb to asking for help.

Here is a further explanation of the question:

I am currently trying to modify a core WordPress(3.91) included calendar widget functions ( is located in wordpress\wp-includes\general-template.php)  so that the calendar shows only the posts from a category group created by me ( Lets call it Events for now).

I AM GOING TO USE MODIFIED VERSION IN A SEPARATE FILE AS A WIDGET KEEPING CORE FILES INTACT AS THEY WERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

So we have:

1. a core function that checks if there were any posts made:

   ```
   $gotsome = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT 1 as test FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' LIMIT 1");
   ```
2. and a core function that makes the appropriate date available to click ( e.g. creates a hyper-link to list of events on that date)

**Get days with posts**

```
$dayswithposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT DAYOFMONTH(post_date)
    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_date >= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-01 00:00:00'
    AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
    AND post_date <= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-{$last_day} 23:59:59'", ARRAY_N);
if ( $dayswithposts ) {
    foreach ( (array) $dayswithposts as $daywith ) {
        $daywithpost[] = $daywith[0];
    }
} else {
    $daywithpost = array();
}

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'camino') !== false || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'safari') !== false)
    $ak_title_separator = "\n";
else
    $ak_title_separator = ', ';

$ak_titles_for_day = array();
$ak_post_titles = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, DAYOFMONTH(post_date) as dom "
    ."FROM $wpdb->posts "
    ."WHERE post_date >= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-01 00:00:00' "
    ."AND post_date <= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-{$last_day} 23:59:59' "
    ."AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'"
);
if ( $ak_post_titles ) {
    foreach ( (array) $ak_post_titles as $ak_post_title ) {

            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
            $post_title = esc_attr( apply_filters( 'the_title', $ak_post_title->post_title, $ak_post_title->ID ) );

            if ( empty($ak_titles_for_day['day_'.$ak_post_title->dom]) )
                $ak_titles_for_day['day_'.$ak_post_title->dom] = '';
            if ( empty($ak_titles_for_day["$ak_post_title->dom"]) ) // first one
                $ak_titles_for_day["$ak_post_title->dom"] = $post_title;
            else
                $ak_titles_for_day["$ak_post_title->dom"] .= $ak_title_separator . $post_title;
    }
}
```

I have found some similar solutions however not entirely appropriate for my situations here:

1. [link1](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/mysql-query-for-all-posts-in-news-category-id-problem?replies=1)
2. [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971729/how-to-get-all-posts-with-all-categories-in-wordpress-through-mysql)

To sum up:

How should I change those queries for my means try to keep it to a maximum to $wpdb notation.

Thanks in advance guys and girls

Comment: There is no reason to ever modify core WordPress files.

Comment: What I meant it used the modified version for my own widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right.. The answer is :

To use the code original code and modify it for your own category all you have to do is change the queries really and this is done simply by adding these lines to certain queries

queries:

$gotsome, $previous, $next, $dayswithposts, $ak_post_titles

universal lines:

after FROM statement:

```
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id =$wpdb->terms.term_id )
```

and an extra condition after your WHERE statement

:

```
AND $wpdb->terms.slug = '$your_category_name'
```

So whole example:

```
$next = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MONTH(post_date) AS month, YEAR(post_date) AS year
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id =$wpdb->terms.term_id )
    WHERE ( $wpdb->posts.post_date > '$thisyear-$thismonth-{$last_day} 23:59:59'
    AND $wpdb->terms.slug = '".$your_category_name."'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post')
        ORDER BY post_date ASC
        LIMIT 1");
```